# How to change a color of a specific citation?

Tags: color, citing

I want most of my citation to be blue in color. So I used

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red}}
```

But I need some of my citation in a different color(say yellow). I tried

```
{\color{yellow} \cite{eg} }
```

to change the specific citation brutally but it doesn't work. What should I do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
... \hypersetup{citecolor=yellow}\cite{eg}\hypersetup{citecolor=blue} ...
```

should do.

Comment: (+1) . optional you also could use a new command for this: preamble: `\newcommand{\citeColored}[2]{\hypersetup{citecolor=#1}\cite{#2}\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}}` and in text:  `\citeColored{yellow}{eg}`.

Answer (score 12):

I like my option slightly better because you don't need to worry about the previous colour:

```
\newcommand{\citeColored}[2]{{\hypersetup{citecolor=#1}\cite{‌​#2}}}
```

Comment: Works really well, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
\definecolor{cite_color}{RGB}{111,111,150} % pure blue: {0,0,128}, light blue:{80,135,208}
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,        
allcolors = black,  
citecolor=cite_color
]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{\textcolor{cite_color}{[}}{\textcolor{cite_color}{]}}{,}{a}{}{;}
```

Comment: Whoops, I realize you mean for a single citation.