# How can I fully colorise bibliography entries with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, color

I would like to colorise certain bibliography entries, e.g. "important" and "award" papers. What I have at the moment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
        isbn=true,
        giveninits=true,
        style=numeric,
        maxnames=99,
        sorting=ydnt,
        defernumbers=true,
        autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{award}

\addtocategory{important}{small}
\addtocategory{award}{big}

\AtEveryBibitem{
\ifcategory{award}%
    {\color{blue}}%
    {}%
\ifcategory{important}%
    {\color{orange}}%
    {}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Main text}

\cite{small}

\cite{big}

\section{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

However, only the bibentry itself is orange (or blue, not shown below), not the reference number next to it. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149753/124842 help you? Please  add a minimal working example with bibliography([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)). that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. No, that answer doesn't help since, still, only the entry itself but not the reference number in front are colorised.

Comment: Related to the problem is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366999/124842 . You can use`\newcommand{\citeColored}[2]{\hypersetup{citecolor=#1}\cite{‌​#2}\hypersetup{citec‌​olor=blue}} and in text: \citeColored{yellow}{eg}`. Please always add a MWE or MWEB.

Comment: yeah, but I would like the bibliography entry to be in a specific color (both reference and reference number), not the reference in the text.

Comment: Please **add** your code( as **a minimal working example**!!). **You can edit your question**. Can you also add a image , that illustrates what you are looking for? Only the bibliography should be colored like this: [1} Example Author , Thesis A, 2017 and not \cite{key2017} in the text(for example)?

Comment: I've added a MWE and picture of the (undesired) output

Comment: @UlrikeFischer . Can you help here? (Ref to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327845/124842). Can `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` and `\printfield` be helfpful here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply use `\AtBeginBibliography` and `\AtEveryBibitem` to set the code for colorizing the bibliography entries only of the `important` category.

P.S. = Since you didn't add an example of your `.bib` file, I've used `biblatex-examples.bib`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
isbn=true,
giveninits=true,
style=numeric,
maxnames=99,
sorting=ydnt,
defernumbers=true,
autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\addtocategory{important}{knuth:ct:a}
\addtocategory{important}{knuth:ct:c}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
    \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\ifcategory{important}%
        {\color{orange}\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
        {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
    }}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifcategory{important}
    {\color{orange}}
    {}}

\begin{document}

    \section{Main text}

    \cite{knuth:ct}
    \cite{knuth:ct:a}
    \cite{knuth:ct:b}       
    \cite{knuth:ct:c}       
    \cite{companion}

    \section{Bibliography}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*

The `\ifcategory` command has this syntax:

```
\ifcategory{hcategoryi}{htruei}{hfalsei}
```

similar to may other `\if`s commands, see `biblatex` manual para. 4.6.2 "Stand-alone Tests".

Within `htruei` or `hfalsei` you can nest as many `\ifcategory`s (or other `\if`s) you want, you only have to pay attention matching all the braces.

Here is an example with three different colors for three different categories:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
isbn=true,
giveninits=true,
style=numeric,
maxnames=99,
sorting=ydnt,
defernumbers=true,
autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\addtocategory{important}{knuth:ct:a}
\addtocategory{important}{knuth:ct:c}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{awards}
\addtocategory{awards}{knuth:ct:b}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{ducks}
\addtocategory{ducks}{companion}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
    \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}%
        {\ifcategory{important}% if
            {\color{orange}\mkbibbrackets{#1}}% then
            {\ifcategory{awards}% else if
                {\color{blue}\mkbibbrackets{#1}}% then
                {\ifcategory{ducks}% else if
                    {\color{green}\mkbibbrackets{#1}}% then
                    {{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%else
                }% end if
            }% end if
        }% end if
}}
\AtEveryBibitem%
    {\ifcategory{important}% if
        {\color{orange}}% then
        {\ifcategory{awards}% else if
            {\color{blue}}% then
            {\ifcategory{ducks}% else if
                {\color{green}}% then
                {}%else
            }% end if
        }% end if
    }% end if

\begin{document}

    \section{Main text}

    \cite{knuth:ct}
    \cite{knuth:ct:a}
    \cite{knuth:ct:b}       
    \cite{knuth:ct:c}       
    \cite{companion}

    \section{Bibliography}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply - that did the trick!

One additional question: What do I have to do to make it work with different colors for multiple categories, e.g. "important" and "awards"?

Comment: @andyknownasabu You're welcome and thank you for accepting my answer! Making it work with multiple categories is very simple, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, fantastic - thank you very much!

Comment: I have a "bonus question" - maybe you also have a solution ready for this: If I also want to colorise the corresponding reference in the text (also within a `\cite{ref1,ref2,ref3}`) - how could I achieve that?

Comment: @andyknownasabu It's feasible but it's better if you ask a follow-up question (that is a new question with this one linked), thank you!

Comment: done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368247/how-to-colorise-specific-entries-in-the-bibliography-and-corresponding-reference

Comment: @andyknownasabu You're welcome!