# How to colorise specific entries in the bibliography and corresponding references in the text?

Tags: biblatex, color

this is a follow-up to a previous question on [how to colorise specific entries in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367195/how-can-i-fully-colorise-bibliography-entries-with-biblatex).

In addition to the bibliography (using the above solution), I would also like to colorise the corresponding references in the text (also within a multi-ref `\cite{ref1,ref2,ref3}`) - how could I achieve that?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Duplicate??: BibTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224568/different-style-color-for-some-specific-references-using-bibtex; natbib: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224596/different-style-color-for-some-specific-references-using-natbib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work for citations and the bibliography. It does not colour the brackets in citations because that could lead to problems with multi-cites.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
isbn=true,
giveninits=true,
style=numeric,
maxnames=99,
sorting=ydnt,
defernumbers=true,
autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\addtocategory{important}{knuth:ct:a}
\addtocategory{important}{knuth:ct:c}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelprefix}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
    {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\color{orange}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{knuth:ct}
  \cite{knuth:ct:a}
  \cite{knuth:ct:b}       
  \cite{knuth:ct:c}       
  \cite{companion}

  \cite{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,companion}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: coloured citations]

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! I guess this also works with multiple categories/colors by simply extending the DeclareFieldFormat commands?!

Comment: @andyknownasabu Of course it does, you can nest `\if`s just as in the other answer.