# Interaction between `refcontext` and `subbibliography`

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to adapt the solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368247/how-to-colorise-specific-entries-in-the-bibliography-and-corresponding-reference) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470852/different-colors-for-each-bib-file-and-custom-prefix). My goal is the following: I want a bibliography split in two sections. The first should be itself split in multiple subsections, by citation type, and citations in this first section should have an extra prefix `AO` and be colored. Citations in in the second section have no prefix, no particular splitting, and no coloring.

I can almost reach something satisfactory, with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file1.bib}
@article{article1,
  author = {Onymous, Anne},
  title  = {First Bibliography: An Journal Article},
  date   = {2000},
}
@inproceedings{inproc1,
  author   = {Onymous, Anne},
  title    = {First Bibliography: A Conference Article},
  date     = {1899},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file2.bib}
@article{article2,
  author = {Writer, William},
  title  = {Second Bibliography: A First Reference},
  date   = {2010},
}
@article{article2bis,
  author = {Poetaster, Paula},
  title  = {Second Bibliography: A Second Reference},
  date   = {1767},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  hyperref=true,
  backref=true,
  giveninits=true,
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  bibstyle=numeric,
  sortcites=false,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxcitenames=2,
  sorting=none,
  defernumbers=true,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{file1.bib}
\addbibresource{file2.bib}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470852/different-colors-for-each-bib-file-and-custom-prefix

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{file1.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,mypapers}, append]
    }
  }
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{file2.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,otherpapers}, append]
    }
  }
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368247/how-to-colorise-specific-entries-in-the-bibliography-and-corresponding-reference
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelprefix}{%
  \ifkeyword{mypapers}
    {\textcolor{red}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifkeyword{mypapers}
    {\textcolor{red}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\begin{document}

  \title{Citation Test}
  \author{Ann Onymous}

\maketitle
\cite{inproc1} \cite{article1} \cite{article2} \cite{article2bis}



\section*{Publications}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=AO]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,keyword=mypapers,heading=subbibliography,title={Publications in Conference Post-Proceedings}]
\printbibliography[type=article,keyword=mypapers,heading=subbibliography,title={Journal Articles}]

\newrefcontext
\printbibliography[keyword=otherpapers]

\end{document}
```

However, labeling is wrong, citations are respectively labeled `AO1`, `AO1` again, `2` and `3`. Ideally, I would like all citations in the first section to share a unique counter, ie be labelled `AO1`, `AO2`, etc. and citations in the second section to start again from 1, ie be labelled `1`, `2`, and so on. I would be content with them starting where the first ones finish, ie at `3` in this example. But having two different citations with the same label is just not possible…

If I remove the `newrefcontext`, I get coloration as expected and unique numbering, but I lose the prefix, which is unfortunate.

I have found the `resetnumbers` key to `\printbibliography`, but have not found how to use it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are nearly there, you just need some `resetnumbers` in your `\printbiliography` commands:

```
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=AO]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,keyword=mypapers,heading=subbibliography,title={Publications in Conference Post-Proceedings}]
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=false,type=article,keyword=mypapers,heading=subbibliography,title={Journal Articles}]

\newrefcontext
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true,keyword=otherpapers]
```

Be aware that when using `defernumbers`, you have to be careful about how many runs of each tool you have. Start with a clean slate with no auxiliary files at all (most editors have a "clean" function to delete all `.aux`, `.bcf` etc. files). Then do `latex->biber->latex->latex`. It is imperative that you run `latex` twice after `biber` when using `defernumbers` (see docs). Most IDEs will tell you to do this as `biblatex` will warn you that using `defernumbers` requires this.

[image]

Technical note: All of the bibliography filtering systems like `type` and `keyword` options to `\printbibliography` plus more advanced filtering with `\defbibfilter` and `\defbibcheck` operate after `biber` has finished and so the `.bbl` datalists still contain all of the entries in the sorting order, with no filtering. So, when you filter things out, you basically leave "holes" in the ordering/numbering and so you have to use `defernumbers` to redo the numbering after the filtering has been applied, hence the extra `latex` run required.