# Missing \endcsname inserted in thesis template

Tags: thesis, missing

[image]

I have a problem with compiling my LaTeX script and I have this error:

> Missing \endcsname inserted

Here is the thesis template which I run and the error basically comes from the line that I have: `\begin{document}`.

Any idea how to fix it?

```
% MNRAS Manuscript Template
\documentclass[useams,onecolumn,usenatbib,twoside]{Thesis}
%\pdfminorversion=5
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lettrine}
%
\usepackage{enumitem} %use to remove spacing in bullet points
%
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage[times,hyper]{Rd}
\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenc}
%\includepdfset{offset=2cm -2cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{pdflscape,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,svgnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
%           citecolor=blue,
%           linkcolor=blue,
%           urlcolor=red,
%           linktocpage=true,
%           hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{final}
\hypersetup{citecolor=CornflowerBlue}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=CornflowerBlue}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=CornflowerBlue}
\def\Planck{\,{\em Planck}}
\def\ie{\,{\rm i.e.}\,}
\def\eg{\,{\rm e.g.}\,}
\def\um{{\rm $\mu$m}\,}
\def\sdss{{\sc sdss}}
\def\viking{{\sc viking}}
\def\hatlas{{\sc h-atlas}}
\def\wise{{\em WISE}}
\def\vista{{\sc vista}}
\def\galex{{\em GALEX}}
\def\lambdar{{\sc lambdar}}
\def\lamsc{{\sc lambdar}}
\def\magphys{{\sc magphys}}
\def\interest{{\sc interest}}
\def\bbf{}
%
% For Revisions: use \bbf to make revised text bold,
%                and uncomment the below. For final
%                submission, re-comment the line to
%                remove the bold-ness.
%\def\bbf{\bf}

\newcommand\aap{A\&A}                % Astronomy and Astrophysics
\let\astap=\aap                          % alternative shortcut
\newcommand\aapr{A\&ARv}             % Astronomy and Astrophysics Review (the)
\newcommand\aaps{A\&AS}              % Astronomy and Astrophysics Supplement Series
\newcommand\actaa{Acta Astron.}      % Acta Astronomica
\newcommand\afz{Afz}                 % Astrofizika
\newcommand\aj{AJ}                   % Astronomical Journal (the)
\newcommand\ao{Appl. Opt.}           % Applied Optics
\let\applopt=\ao                         % alternative shortcut
\newcommand\aplett{Astrophys.~Lett.} % Astrophysics Letters
\newcommand\apj{ApJ}                 % Astrophysical Journal
\newcommand\apjl{ApJ}                % Astrophysical Journal, Letters
\let\apjlett=\apjl                       % alternative shortcut
\newcommand\apjs{ApJS}               % Astrophysical Journal, Supplement
\let\apjsupp=\apjs                       % alternative shortcut
% The following journal does not appear to exist! Disabled.
%\newcommand\apspr{Astrophys.~Space~Phys.~Res.} % Astrophysics Space Physics Research
\newcommand\apss{Ap\&SS}             % Astrophysics and Space Science
\newcommand\araa{ARA\&A}             % Annual Review of Astronomy and Astrophysics
\newcommand\arep{Astron. Rep.}       % Astronomy Reports
\newcommand\aspc{ASP Conf. Ser.}     % ASP Conference Series
\newcommand\azh{Azh}                 % Astronomicheskii Zhurnal
\newcommand\baas{BAAS}               % Bulletin of the American Astronomical Society
\newcommand\bac{Bull. Astron. Inst. Czechoslovakia} % Bulletin of the Astronomical Institutes of Czechoslovakia
\newcommand\bain{Bull. Astron. Inst. Netherlands} % Bulletin Astronomical Institute of the Netherlands
\newcommand\caa{Chinese Astron. Astrophys.} % Chinese Astronomy and Astrophysics
\newcommand\cjaa{Chinese J.~Astron. Astrophys.} % Chinese Journal of Astronomy and Astrophysics
\newcommand\fcp{Fundamentals Cosmic Phys.}  % Fundamentals of Cosmic Physics
\newcommand\gca{Geochimica Cosmochimica Acta}   % Geochimica Cosmochimica Acta
\newcommand\grl{Geophys. Res. Lett.} % Geophysics Research Letters
\newcommand\iaucirc{IAU~Circ.}       % IAU Cirulars
\newcommand\icarus{Icarus}           % Icarus
\newcommand\japa{J.~Astrophys. Astron.} % Journal of Astrophysics and Astronomy
\newcommand\jcap{J.~Cosmology Astropart. Phys.} % Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics
\newcommand\jcp{J.~Chem.~Phys.}      % Journal of Chemical Physics
\newcommand\jgr{J.~Geophys.~Res.}    % Journal of Geophysics Research
\newcommand\jqsrt{J.~Quant. Spectrosc. Radiative Transfer} % Journal of Quantitiative Spectroscopy and Radiative Transfer
\newcommand\jrasc{J.~R.~Astron. Soc. Canada} % Journal of the RAS of Canada
\newcommand\memras{Mem.~RAS}         % Memoirs of the RAS
\newcommand\memsai{Mem. Soc. Astron. Italiana} % Memoire della Societa Astronomica Italiana
\newcommand\mnassa{MNASSA}           % Monthly Notes of the Astronomical Society of Southern Africa
\newcommand\mnras{MNRAS}             % Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society
%\newcommand\na{New~Astron.}          % New Astronomy
\newcommand\nar{New~Astron.~Rev.}    % New Astronomy Review
\newcommand\nat{Nature}              % Nature
\newcommand\nphysa{Nuclear Phys.~A}  % Nuclear Physics A
\newcommand\phdt{PhD.T}        % PhD Thesis
\newcommand\pra{Phys. Rev.~A}        % Physical Review A: General Physics
\newcommand\prb{Phys. Rev.~B}        % Physical Review B: Solid State
\newcommand\prc{Phys. Rev.~C}        % Physical Review C
\newcommand\prd{Phys. Rev.~D}        % Physical Review D
\newcommand\pre{Phys. Rev.~E}        % Physical Review E
\newcommand\prl{Phys. Rev.~Lett.}    % Physical Review Letters
\newcommand\pasa{Publ. Astron. Soc. Australia}  % Publications of the Astronomical Society of Australia
\newcommand\pasp{PASP}               % Publications of the Astronomical Society of the Pacific
\newcommand\pasj{PASJ}               % Publications of the Astronomical Society of Japan
\newcommand\physrep{Phys.~Rep.}      % Physics Reports
\newcommand\physscr{Phys.~Scr.}      % Physica Scripta
\newcommand\planss{Planet. Space~Sci.} % Planetary Space Science
\newcommand\procspie{Proc.~SPIE}     % Proceedings of the Society of Photo-Optical Instrumentation Engineers
\newcommand\rmxaa{Rev. Mex. Astron. Astrofis.} % Revista Mexicana de Astronomia y Astrofisica
\newcommand\qjras{QJRAS}             % Quarterly Journal of the RAS
\newcommand\sci{Science}             % Science
\newcommand\skytel{Sky \& Telesc.}   % Sky and Telescope
\newcommand\solphys{Sol.~Phys.}      % Solar Physics
\newcommand\sovast{Soviet~Ast.}      % Soviet Astronomy (aka Astronomy Reports)
\newcommand\ssr{Space Sci. Rev.}     % Space Science Reviews
\newcommand\zap{Z.~Astrophys.}       % Zeitschrift fuer Astrophysik

%%%%%
% Rd functions
%%%%%
%\def\AsIs{\bgroup\let\do\@makeother\Rd@AsIs@dospecials\@noligs\obeylines\@vobeyspaces\parskip\z@skip\Rd@AsIsX}
%\def\Rd@AsIs@dospecials{\do\$\do\&\do\#\do\^\do\_\do\%\do\~}
%\def\Rd@AsIsX#1{\normalfont #1\egroup}
% Arxiver Figure selection: Declare Figures to show on Arxiver
% ___Leave Commented out, just change the Figure Names___
% __Just use Figure Names, Path is determined internally__
%@arxiver{Figure1.png,Figure4.pdf,Figure5.eps}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        %\vskip 40\p@
        \vskip 100\p@
}}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        %\vskip 40\p@
        \vskip 100\p@
}}
%%%%%
\makeindex{}
\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.gif,.jpg}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Title Page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}



    \textsc {\LARGE The University of SomeWhere}\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc {\LARGE  \& }\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc {\LARGE }\\[0.2cm]
    \textsc {\LARGE }\\[1.5cm]
    \textsc{School of Lablab}\\[0.5cm]
    \LARGE PhD Thesis\\[0.5cm]

    % Title
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    { \huge \bfseries
My Thesis Title
}\\[0.4cm]
    \HRule \\[0.5cm]


% Author and supervisor
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
S \textsc{K\vspace{2cm}}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisors:} \\
W/Prof. S \textsc{D}\\
A/Prof. A \textsc{R}\\
Dr. L \textsc{D}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

 \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./images/logo.png}
 \end{minipage} \\[0.5cm]

    % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today}

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Preamble
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
\include{Preamble}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Chapter One: Introduction
\include{ChapterOne}
%Chapter Two: 
\include{ChapterTwo}
%Chapter Three: 
\include{ChapterThree}
%Chapter Four: 
\include{ChapterFour}
%Chapter Five: 
\include{ChapterFive}
%Chapter Six: 
\include{ChapterSix}


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliographystyle{mnras}
\bibliography{library}
\appendix
\include{AppendixOne}
\include{AppendixTwo}
\include{AppendixThree}
\printindex{}
\end{document}
```

and here is the `Thesis.cls`:

```
%% This is file `Thesis.cls', based on 'ECSthesis.cls', by Steve R. Gunn  
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% Created by Steve R. Gunn, modified by Sunil Patel: www.sunilpatel.co.uk

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]

\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
              [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{12pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand\Declaration[1]{
\btypeout{Declaration of Authorship}
\addtotoc{Declaration of Authorship}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
%\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\huge\bf Declaration of Authorship\par}\end{center}
%\vskip 60\p@
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null
%\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\year}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 4cm}  % left margin
                        { 2cm}  % top margin
                        { 2cm}  % right margin
                        { 2cm}  % bottom margin
                        {  10pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep

\raggedbottom
%\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
\setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{lstpatch}
\lstset{captionpos=b,
        frame=tb,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keepspaces=true}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
        language=Matlab,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=true,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={green},urlcolor={blue},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
   \let\\\space
}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\examiner}[1]{\def\examname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\def\degreename{#1}}
\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\def\authornames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\addresses}[1]{\def\addressnames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\university}[1]{\def\univname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\UNIVERSITY}[1]{\def\UNIVNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\deptname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\DEPARTMENT}[1]{\def\DEPTNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\group}[1]{\def\groupname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\GROUP}[1]{\def\GROUPNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\FACULTY}[1]{\def\FACNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\subjectname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\def\keywordnames{#1}}
\supervisor  {}
\examiner    {}
\degree      {}
\authors     {}
\university  {\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {The University}}
                {The University}}
\UNIVERSITY  {\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {THE UNIVERSITY}}
                {THE UNIVERSITY}}
\department  {\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {School}}
                {School}}
\DEPARTMENT  {\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {SCHOOL OF PHYSICS}}
                {SCHOOL OF PHYSICS}}
\group       {\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {International}}
                {International}}
\GROUP       {\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {INTERNATIONAL}}
                {INTERNATIONAL}}
\faculty     {\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {Physical Science}}
                {Physical Science}}
\FACULTY     {\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {PHYSICAL SCIENCE}}
                {PHYSICAL SCIENCE}}
\addresses   {}
\subject     {}
\keywords    {}
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      \vfill
      {\huge \bf \@title \par}
      \vfill
      {\LARGE by \par}
      \smallskip
      {\LARGE \authornames \par}
      \vfill
      {\large This thesis is presented for the degree of \par}
      {\large Doctor of Philosophy \par}
    {\large at the University  \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\Large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
}
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
  \btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfil
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\huge{\textit{Abstract}} \par}
  \end{center}
}
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
   \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
\btypeout{List of Figures}
\addtotoc{List of Figures}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{
\btypeout{List of Tables}
\addtotoc{List of Tables}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \@starttoc{lot}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
\btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listconstants{Physical Constants}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofconstants[2]{
\btypeout{\listconstants}
\addtotoc{\listconstants}
    \chapter*{\listconstants
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listconstants}{\MakeUppercase\listconstants}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
    \chapter*{\listnomenclature
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{
\btypeout{Acknowledgements}
\addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgements}} \par}\end{center}
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null

}
\newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
\btypeout{Dedicatory}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\Large \sl #1}\end{center}
\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
}
\renewcommand\backmatter{
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \addtotoc{\bibname}
  \btypeout{\bibname}
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `Thesis.cls'.
```

and finally my Preamble.tex as:

```
%
% Preamble
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Abstract
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\begin{minipage}{13cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{center}
\vspace{0.25in}
{\Huge \bfseries Abstract}
\end{center}
\input{Abstract}
\end{minipage}
\clearpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Quote
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{minipage}{13cm}
\vspace{3in}
\begin{center}
%{\Large\hfill``This is a terrible choice for a quote!''\hfill }\\
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Acknowledgements
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%Acknowledgements
\clearpage
\begin{minipage}{13cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{center}
\vspace{1in}
{\Huge \bfseries Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
\input{Acknowledgements}
\end{minipage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               ToC
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               LoF
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
\listoffigures

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               LoT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
\listoftables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Preface
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
\begin{minipage}{13cm}
\begin{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
{\Huge \bfseries Preface}
\end{center}
\input{Preface}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Scrap that template. But where do you got it from to begin with?

Comment: This works as a default temp in Uni website, and I wonder because it was working a few hours ago but suddenly stop to compile with no reason!

Comment: you haven't given a link to Thesis.cls so no one can test this or comment on the error, nor have you shown the error you got (copy the whole error from `!` to `?` from the log file and show it in the question, but errors at begin document are normally from the aux file so start by deleting that file.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I added the error and Thesis.cls as attached.

Comment: No I do not see the log file error, you have shown a screenshot of a summary of the editor from some editor but that has no useful information.  Did you delete the `.aux` file?

Answer (score 0):

You commented out the use of the `hyperref` package, thus causing the `\hypersetup` command not to be recognized. Get rid of the `%`s in front of lines 32--37. See the documentation for the `hyperref` package regarding setting colors for the various link types.

Comment: I commented those lines out but still doesn't work and give me a new error as "option clash for package hyperref" on top up the previous one. Actually I didn't have any problem with these lines before.

Comment: @Soheil With hyperref package *un*-commented out, code compiles OK for me.

Comment: Thanks @Cicada. It works now. But do you have any idea why it is clashed with hyperref? I only use this package to colorize my citations? Is there any alternative?

Comment: @Soheil Nothing clashes when I run the code (but my `Thesis.cls` is part of MikTek; I'll compare). Colorized citations is a common question: `hyperref` solution (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366996/how-to-change-a-color-of-a-specific-citation); biblatex solutions (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253927/color-citation-using-biblatex-in-text-references-issue-with-postnote-bibl ; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369710/beamer-citation-coloring ; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351379/beamer-biblatex-biber-change-color-of-citations-globally; and so on.)

Comment: @Soheil The `Thesis.cls` code you posted is already loading a dozen packages (including `hyperref` with its own option), and doing a lot of option-processing. Then in your preamble, you are loading a lot of the same packages, with and without options, basically re-wiring how `Thesis.cls` works. It's not surprising there will be errors. My impression is that `Thesis.cls` should be doing most of the work for you. Remove all packages from your preamble that `Thesis.cls` is already calling. Contact the maintainer of the class for instructions on how to use it.

Comment: @Soheil The `thesis.cls` that is part of MikTek is a completely different file from the `Thesis.cls` code that you have posted. Were there any instructions at the place where you got the code from?

Comment: @Soheil I concur with @johannes_b: scrap that template. A quick Google reveals that the `Sunil's Garden` site is now hosting Johannes Böttcher's 2017 `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` from LaTeXTemplates.com as a thesis template, instead of the modified version 2007 of Professor Gunn's template at the University of Southampton (now up to 2018 version, for the University).

Comment: And i wouldn't use Mastersdoctoralthesis either. Go with a minimal template instead.

Comment: @Cicada Thats totally right. Now I see why code doesn't work properly as I compile similar packages from different directories. The code is now working as normal. Also thanks for your recommendation for Thesis template.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, I guess @Cicada provided me with the best answer.

Comment: If you look closely at my response, I said that you should UNCOMMENT the lines having to do with hyperref . . . I also had to comment out all `\include` lines, the reference to the graphic, and anything having to do with external files.